# Alt-C not working in Blender 2.8

Tags: conversion

I want to convert my text object to mesh. In 2.79 it was Alt-C, are the keys changed for 2.80?

---

I browsed it externally and I got some thing like this image as answer..
[image]

but any shortcut-keys will be easy to work!
If you know one, you can comment below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> was removed from the default keymap in 2.80 unfortunately. You can bring it back by just right-clicking on the option in the menu and selecting Assign Shortcut. If you do that you will have a shortcut for the specific operation and not the convert menu like it was in previous versions. If you wanted to bring it back exactly like it was, you need to go to the User Preferences(<kbd>F4</kbd> -> <kbd>p</kbd>), find it using Key-Binding search mode and just remove the Target property there so it is unset and you are presented with the choice when you hit the hotkey.

[image]

Comment: I wonder why Blender 2.8 don't have default setting for this, anyways it is helpful, thanks for your efforts.

Comment: There seems to be this new idea of cleaner and lighter keymap so that users customuze more and there is space on the keyboard to make usable shortcuts for what is needed individually.

Answer (score 4):

If you want use "convert to mesh from curve" on curve object. You can select the curve object  in object mode and use "right mouse button and select" "convert to Mesh". [image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

So I do not use left click to select.  I use right click; so under this instance you have to go to OBJECT THEN to convert to. They gave us quickfavorites menu so I don't complain.  Right Click on it then add to quick favorites and then Q stands for quick favorites.